# NiFi - Processor has stopped but task still running

Tags: apache-nifi

It works fine these days. Suddenly Processors still have task running even been stopped, and the running task need to terminate manually.

Any thoughts?

[image]

### update 1

I use [nipyapi](https://github.com/Chaffelson/nipyapi) to manipulate some processors to start and stop over and over again. There are the APIs I used

```
nipyapi.canvas.get_processor(identifier=p_id, identifier_type='id')
nipyapi.canvas.get_process_group(identifier=pg_id, identifier_type='id')
nipyapi.canvas.schedule_processor(processor=p_id, scheduled=True, refresh=True)
```

I restart NiFi and problem solved, but after executing those APIs many times (about 10000 times, `grep processor id | wc -l`) problem occurred.

I reckon those APIs create a lot web connections and not being stopped.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Stopping a processor is really just telling the scheduler not to trigger any more executions. It is often the case that an already-triggered thread is still executing after the processor has been stopped, which is why the Terminate option was added.

Comment: I agreed. Using `GenerateFlowFile` for example(because this processor's task finish quickly), at the very beginning(nifi.sh start), task would finish while hitting processor `stop` action. But after triggered lots of processor `start`/`stop` actions, task remained executing while the processor been stoped after minutes! I don't think it would be terminated so I had to restart nifi. (NiFi-1.9.2)

Comment: It can be re-produced in my production environment which has 2 nodes. But working fine in single node NiFi environment both linux(server) and windows(local). I don't know how to find out this problem.